# Alternative Mersenne numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers

Let $\ b\in\mathbb Z,\ $ and $\ |b|>1.\ $ Call
$$ M_b(n)\ :=\ \frac{b^n-1}{b-1} $$
to be $n$-th Mersenne number mod $b$. The necessary condition for $\ M_b(n)\ $ to be a prime is that $\ n\ $ is a prime.

*The two cases of $\ |b|=2\ $ seem the most attractive.*

Let $\ A_b := M_{-b}\ $ for every $\ b>1. $ Call $\ A_b(n)\ $ to be the base $b$ alternative Mersenne numbers.

For b=2 there is the Lucas-Lehmer test.

**Question:** Is there or can you provide (makeup) a similar test for $\ A_2(p)\ $ alternative Mersenne numbers?

> ---

This would very likely produce new large primes. Naively, there seems to be more base 2 alternative Mersenne primes than the classical Mersenne primes. An actual theorem along these lines would be wonderful.

Comment: According to [MathWorld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/WagstaffPrime.html) all recent primality proofs of this type of  primes have used elliptic curve primality proving.

Comment: Are you familiar with The Cunningham Project, https://homes.cerias.purdue.edu/~ssw/cun/third/index.html Factorizations of $b^n\pm1$, $b = 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 10, 11, 12$, up to High Powers?

Comment: Some examples of these primes are at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repunit.